# Find a word in a file and print it in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file in `/home/{user}/client.log`.

`clinet.log` contains a work `lcid`.

How can I find a word `lcid` in a file `client.log` and print it using bash.

Comment: I used grep 'lcid' client.log and it returned ,"lcid":"6a3953a9f93a49fab513b1c1a48a5ac9"  but I want only the value of lcid in without quote

Comment: Look in the grep man page.

Comment: Please show an example line from the log file that contains the lcid. I suppose `"lcid":"6a3953a9f93a49fab513b1c1a48a5ac9"` is  such an example? The option `-o` of gnu grep seems what you need to add.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

use the following command:
`grep "lcid" . -R`

Comment: Thanks user3579415

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the additional information you provided this will do the trick for you:

```
sed -n "s/.*lcid.:.\(\w*\)./\1/p" client.log
```

- -n -- don't print
- s -- substitute
- .* -- match anything
- lcid -- literal match
- . -- match any single character
- : -- literal match
- . -- match any one character
- \( -- begin capture group one
- \w* -- any amount of word characters
- \) -- end capture group one
- . -- match any single character
- \1 -- replace with capture group one
- p -- print it

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got this working by using the following command

grep 'lcid' client.log | cut -d'"' -f4